# What are the maximal ideals of $C_0 (X),$ where $X$ is a locally compact Hausdorff space?

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras

[Crossposted from MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4278954/what-are-the-maximal-ideals-of-c-0-x-where-x-is-a-locally-compact-hausdor)

> How do the maximal ideals of $C_0(X)$ look like where $X$ is a locally compact Hausdorff space?

I know that if $X$ is a compact Hausdorff space then the maximal ideals of $C(X)$ are of the form $I_{c} : = \left \{f \in C(X)\ |\ f(c) = 0 \right \},$ for some $c \in X.$ I can also able to show that if $X$ is a locally compact Hausdorff space then $I_{c}$ is a maximal ideal of $C_0 (X)$ but can't able to prove the converse of that. Could anyone please help me in this regard?

Thanks a bunch.

**EDIT** $:$ Let $X^+$ denote the one point compactification of $X.$ Let $\varphi : C_0(X) \longrightarrow \mathbb C$ be a multiplicative linear functional on $C_0(X).$ Then it can be extended to a multiplicative linear functional $\overline {\varphi} : C(X^+) \longrightarrow \mathbb C$ defined by $\overline {\varphi} (f) = \varphi \left (f\ \big |_{X} \right ).$ Also given any $f \in C_0(X)$ there is an unique way to extend it to a function $\overline {f} \in C(X^+)$ as follows $:$ $$\overline {f} (x) = \begin{cases} f(x) & x \in X \\ 0 & x = \infty \end{cases}$$ Now take any $f \in C_0(X).$  Then since $X^+$ is compact we have $\varphi (f) = \overline {\varphi} (\overline {f}) = \overline {f} (c),$ for some $c \in X^+.$ If $c = \infty$ we have $\varphi \equiv 0$ i.e. $\varphi$ is a zero linear functional on $C_0(X).$ Otherwise there always exixts some $c \in X$ such that $\varphi (f) = f(c),$ for all $f \in C_0(X).$ So for any non-zero multiplicative linear functional $\varphi$ on $C_0(X)$ we have $\text {Ker}\ (\varphi) = \{f \in C_0(X)\ |\ f(c) = 0 \} = I_{c},$ for some $c \in X.$ Since we know that maximal ideals in any Banach algebra $A$ are precisely the kernels of non-zero multiplicative linear functionals on $A$ and $C_0(X)$ is a Banach algebra (in fact a $C^{\ast}$-algebra) we are through.

**Possible Mistake** $:$ I think where my above argument goes wrong is the stage where I assume $f\ \big |_{X} \in C_0 (X)$ whenever $f \in C(X^{+}).$ Instead when $f \in C_0 (X^+)$ this happens. Now we need to search for maximal ideals of $\{f \in C(X^+)\ |\ f(\infty) = 0 \}.$ So the above is not a valid argument. What my above argument shows is the following $:$

> Multiplicative linear functionals on $C(X)$ are precisely evaluations even if $X$ is locally compact.

So the original question ultimately boils down to the following question  $:$

> Can we always extend every multiplicative linear functional on $C_0(X)$ to a multiplicative linear functional on $C(X)$ if $X$ is a locally compact Hausdorff space?

Comment: What is $C_0(X)$? Functions with compact support or functions going to zero at infinity?

Comment: @Denis Nardin$:$ Functions vanishing at infinity.

Comment: If $\varphi$ is a multiplicative linear functional on $C_0(X)$, then isn't $\varphi^+ : c + f \mapsto c + \varphi(f)$ a multiplicative linear functional on $C(X^+)$, where we write $f$ also for the extension of $f$ to $X^+$ that vanishes at $\infty$, and $c$ also for the constant function on $X^+$ with value $c$?  Then $\varphi^+$ is the evaluation at some point $x \in X^+$ ($x = \infty$ if and only if $\varphi = 0$), and $\ker(\varphi) = \ker(\varphi^+) \cap C_0(X)$.

Comment: Although the question has received answers, or outlines of answers, here, it belongs more properly on MSE. It has only been on MSE for less than 24 hours; in future, perhaps try waiting a bit longer before crossposting here.

Comment: Note: if $X$ is compact, the maximal ideals of $C_0(X)$ are automatically closed, and are exactly the mentioned $I_c$ for $c\in X$. If $X$ is locally compact, but not compact, there are also dense maximal ideals. For instance, the set $C_c(X)$ of compactly supported functions is already a proper dense ideal of $C_0(X)$, and it is included in no $I_c$.

Comment: @PietroMajer: Is $I_{c}$ a maximal ideal of $C_0 (X)\ $?

Comment: Yes, as you said.

Comment: @PietroMajer: Where have I said that? I took an ideal $J$ properly containing $I_{c}.$ Then there exists $g \in J$ such that such that $g(c) \neq 0.$ Then $h = \frac {g} {g(c)} \in J.$ I am trying to show that $1 - h \in I_{c} \subseteq J$ but the only problem I am facing is that I can't conclude that $1 - h \in C_0(X)$ as it is not vanishing at infinity. If I could do that then $1 \in J$ and we are through.

Comment: @PietroMajer: I have said that $I_{c}$ is a maximal ideal of $C(X),$ if $X$ is a compact Hausdorff space. I haven't proved anything valid for $C_0(X)$ if $X$ is a locally compact, non-compact Hausdorff space.

Comment: A good reason why $I_c$ is a maximal ideal is that it is a linear hyperplane (a codimension $1$ linear subspace), namely, the kernel of the evaluation at $c$.

Comment: Oh right. Since kernels of non-zero multiplicative linear functionals are necessarily maximal ideals of the underlying Banach algebra we are through. But how do I guarantee that such an evaluation is always non-zero? In other words given $c \in X$ can we always find some $f \in C_0(X)$ such that $f(c) \neq 0$ @PietroMajer? For specific $X ( = (0,1)$ (say)) it is easy to see. But for arbitrary $X$ (LCH) is it always true?

Comment: Because X was assumed to be a locally compact Hausdorff space, hence completely regular (so for instance, for any c and any nbd U of c, there are functions  with f(c)=1 and vanishing outside U).
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tychonoff_space

Comment: @PietroMajer: Just now a question has struck in my mind which is the following $:$ What will happen if we consider closed maximal ideals of $C_0(X)\ $? Are they all of the form $I_{c}$ for dome $c \in X\ $?

Answer (score 1):

The maximal ideals are exactly the kernels of point evaluation. This is proved in  Chapter II, Prop. 7.4.5 on page 120 of

- Z. Semadeni: Banach spaces of continuous functions. Warsaw 1971.

Comment: Is the pdf of this book available online? I have searched for it but unfortunately couldn't able to find it anywhere.